# Remove line if the second or second to last character is a space in the first column of a CSV

Tags: awk, sed

First of all, I apologise for not giving an example of what I've tried because with this one I really don't know where to begin. It's a job for SED or AWK, that's about as far as I can get.

I would like to remove lines if:

- The second character is a space in the first column
- The second to last character is a space in the first column

Example input

```
John Smith|Chicago|IL
J Smith|Chicago|IL
Jane Brown|New York|NY
Jane B|New York|NY
```

Expected Output

```
John Smith|Chicago|IL
Jane Brown|New York|NY
```

The files are | delimited, some contain 4 columns of data, others contain 5 or more (I know it's bad formatting, but it's data collected by a NGO that I'm trying to help them with) but in each case I'd like this to happen just for the first column of the file.

Comment: You can try by looking up how to use `awk` and `sed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply translated your two criteria into regexp and use `grep` with option `-v` to remove these patterns

**The second character is a space in the first column** -> `^[^|]`

**The second to last character is a space in the first column** -> `^[^|]* [^|]\|`

```
grep -Ev '(^[^|] )|(^[^|]* [^|]\|)' <input>
```

Result:

```
John Smith|Chicago|IL
Jane Brown|New York|NY
```

Comment: Perhaps `grep -v '^[^|] \|^[^|]* [^|]|' file` would work too?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} substr($1,2,1)==" " || substr($1,length($1)-1,1)==" "{next} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F\| '{s=split($1,a,"")} !(a[2]==" " || a[s-1]==" ")' file
John Smith|Chicago|IL
Jane Brown|New York|NY
```

It splits the first field inn to array `a` and length in `s`.  Then test second and second last if empty.
Easy to read and easy to understand how it works :)

Comment: Use of a null string as a field separator (3rd arg to split()) is undefined behavior per POSIX so that'll do different things in different awks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'|' '$1 !~ /^. | .$/' file
John Smith|Chicago|IL
Jane Brown|New York|NY
```

Answer (score 1):

Smaller version of "Corentin Limier" answer

```
  grep -Ev '(^. )|(^* .\|)' filename
```

Result:

```
 John Smith|Chicago|IL
 Jane Brown|New York|NY
```

This may also be possible with "sed" command

```
  sed '/^. /d' filename | sed '/ .|/d'
```

Comment: Your first pattern does not work for lines like this `| hello|world` (empty first column) and your second pattern does not work for lines like this `hello|world a|b` (penultimate space on other columns) + your second pattern should be : `(^.* .\|)`